# jAlert not working, get nothing when submitting the form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to program what should be an easy concept: a webpage with a form (two textboxes) and when the form is submitted if the two textboxes do not have the same content, then an alert pops up.

I  have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Examples of using jQuery Alerts</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.alerts.css" />
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function() {
                $('#myform').submit( function() {
                    var x = $('#mytext').val();
                    var y = $('#mytext2').val();
                    if ( x!=y) {
                        jAlert('Values do not match','Info!');
                    return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myform" id="myform" action="#">
            <input type="text" id="mytext" />
            <input type="text" id="mytext2" />
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

All file names are checked and they are correct, but I get nothing when I submit the form (same as when I do `$.jAlert())` - if `jAlert` is replaced by `alert` everything works, but I get the standard Javascript alert). Where am I am going wrong?

Regards,
George

Comment: Can you share url of plugin `jAlert`? There are so many on the web. And even better if you could provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code. The problem is in your jquery.alerts.js. Its using '`$.browser`' in 2 or 3 places inside the plugin.

The `$.browser` method has been removed as of jQuery 1.9.

> [**`jQuery.browser() removed`**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)
>
> The `jQuery.browser()` method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and is removed in 1.9. **If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery Migrate plugin.** We recommend using feature detection with a library such as Modernizr.
>
> — [jQuery Core 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/).

As stated in the Upgrade Guide you can try using the [jQuery Migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) to restore this functionality and let jQuery Tools work.

You have remove that from the plugin to work this otherwise you need to change the plugin or use the jquery version below Jquery 1.9